# What's wrong with this derivation of velocity of an object in a gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Since a mass (say a piece of satellite) falling towards a significantly bigger mass (say the earth) experiences an acceleration g=GM/x^2, and since g is an acceleration and you differentiate with respect to time you get velocity, v. But as we all know if you differentiate g with respect to x you get gravitational potential, V.

So,

v = integral(g)dt = integral(g)dx*(dt/dx)
And since v is defined dx/dt and as a result dt/dt=1/v, the equation simplifies to

v^2= integral(GM/x^2)dx = -GM/x + constant
When x=infinity, v=0 so constant = 0
So v^2= -GM/x

Why do I have a minus sign? Where did it come from/where have I gone wrong in this derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the derivation you're looking for:

$$g=-\frac{GM}{x^2}$$

The minus sign stems from the fact that $x$ and $g$ point in opposite directions.

$$g=a=\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{GM}{x^2}$$

$$\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{GM}{x^2}$$

$$vdv=-\frac{GM}{x^2}dx$$

Integrate between $x_1,0$ and $x_2,v$:

$$\int_0^v vdv=-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{GM}{x^2}dx$$

$$\frac{v^2}{2}=GM(\frac{1}{x_2}-\frac{1}{x_1})$$

Multiply both sides with the mass of the object $m$ and you have an energy conservation relation: kinetic energy $K$ change equals potential energy $V$ change:

$$\Delta K = \Delta V.$$

Comment: What if say an object artificially started at 4000ms^-1 at a radius of 20*10^6m, what would its speed be at 10*10^6m?

Comment: The left hand side becomes: $\frac{v_2^2}{2}-\frac{v_1^2}{2}$. Then plug in the numbers.

Comment: Also why is it delta V, surely that's change in gp not change in KE?

Comment: $V$ here stands for potential energy.

Comment: Ok thanks, last question, when you assign limits surely if you assign v and o for LHS you should assign x and infinity for RHS? Or do you assume v=0 at x1?

Comment: You can assume *anything* you want it to be. I used $x_1,0$. Start from $x_1,v_1$ if you prefer, just get the determined integral right and you can do what you want.